# Trying to write a function that displays data in an SQL database

Tags: php

Trying to write a function that displays the id, and filepath of all public content in an SQL database. Here's what I have so far, but it failed to run.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "pricosha";

    // Create connection
    $connection = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    //Added two extra variables, username and content_name
    $query = "SELECT id, username, file_path, content_name FROM Content";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    //Loop through the results of the query
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. " Username: " . $row["username"]. " File Path: " . $row["file_path"]. " Content Name: " . $row["content_name"]. "<br>";
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: `$connection` != `$conn`.  also debug 101, check `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable for create the connection to mysql is **$connection**, while you use **$conn** for this :

```
$conn->connect_error
```

and this :

```
$conn->close();
```

Now try to change **$conn** to **$connection** or just change this :

```
$connection = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

to this :

```
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

So far now, the function mysql_connect, mysql_query, and others have been deprecated. You need to change it to mysqli I think. Try this.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pricosha";

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die(mysqli_errno());

$query = "SELECT id, username, file_path, content_name FROM Content";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. " Username: " . $row["username"]. " File Path: " . $row["file_path"]. " Content Name: " . $row["content_name"]. "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```